# ajax redirect issue

Tags: ajax

i want to redirect form after ( success ) to another page. i use this code

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
> $("#ajax-form").submit(function(){
>     $.post(
>         "ajaxContact/ajax-register.php",
>         $("#ajax-form").serialize(),
>         function(data){
>             if (data.success)
>                 $("span#ajax-message").css({'color':'green'});
>                window.location("index.html");
>             else
>                 $("span#ajax-message").css({'color':'red'});
>             $("span#ajax-message").html(data.message);
>         },
>         "json"
>     );
>     return false;
> });
> ```
>
> });

how to redirect.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just redirect the page there, this should work:

```
if(data.success)
    window.location = "url";
```

**Updated:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#ajax-form").submit(function()
     {
          $.post("ajaxContact/ajax-register.php", $("#ajax-form").serialize(), 
          function(data)
          {
                if (data.success)
                {
                    //If successful...
                    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
                }
                else
                {
                    //If unsuccessful...
                    alert("Post was unsuccessful."); 
                }                    
          },"json");

    return false;
    });
});
```

That should work for you as long as your post is returning successfully. Here's a demo using a confirm to imitate your Post:

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/F5vEn/1/)

Comment: Hadn't seen it since you updated your code - I'll check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```